# Can't fold json sections for deep objects in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I have a js file which has only one duty which is to export a huge json file like below:

```
export default {
     // very deep json definiton.
}
```

I realize that folding / unfolding feature can not be applied for deep objects in this json definition. For the first 21 levels of the json, i can see the arrow signs on the left side of the editor window, but for deeper levels it basically starts not showing up.
For the time being, I have no chance to decrease the size of the json.
I also tried to increase **JSON: Max item computed** parameter in Settings but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

You may suggest that creating a .json file and directly consume it, but syntax highlighting for js is much more readable than of a json file . And, VSC forced me to use double quoting for json that is very annoying to me.

Comment: IS it a folding problem?  VSCode has a default maximum number of folding regions.  In v1.64 you can increase that beyond the old 5000 maximum in the setting:   `Editor: Maximum Folding Regions` .  Perhaps that helps?